# How do I add select options from an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, oop, react-hooks

I am trying to create a dropdown list based on a object I have. I can't think of a way to do it that's not completely convoluted and the solutions I have come up with don't work either. I'm new to react and stackoverflow so I am not sure if just asking for advice is seen as okay. Forgive me if it's not. I am building it with React. Is there a way to do this that I am missing. Again sorry if you are not supposed to ask for help here

I have created the component as follows

```
const HardwearForm = ({isActive, Products, outputObj, setOutputObj}) => {

const handleSelect = e => {
    let newParentNode = e.target;
    let selectedNumber = newParentNode.options.selectedIndex;
    let choice = newParentNode.options[selectedNumber].value;               
    setOutputObj(outputObj[newParentNode.id] = choice);        
    console.log(outputObj)        
}        

useEffect(() => { 
    let parentNode = document.getElementById("make");
    Object.keys(Products[isActive]["hardwear"]).forEach(key => {            
    let newOption = document.createElement('option');
    newOption.value = key;
    newOption.innerText = key;
    parentNode.appendChild(newOption);
    })
},[isActive, Products]); 

return (
    <div>
    <select name="make" className="hardwear" id="make" onChange={handleSelect}>
        <option value="*">Manufacturer</option>
    </select>
    <select name="model" className="hardwear" id="model"></select>
    {isActive === "handset"|| isActive==="tablet"?
    <>
    <select name="storage" className="hardwear" id="storage""></select></>:""}
    {isActive === "handset"|| isActive==="tablet" ||isActive=== "watch"?
    <>
    <select name="color" className="hardwear"></select></>:""}
    {isActive === "handset"|| isActive==="watch"?
    <>
)
```

The basic idea is I have a menu with a few buttons. Those buttons update the isActive state, which then causes the useEffect to run and populate the first select with the options. That works fine. I've then set it up so once a selection in the first dropdown is chosen it fires the handleSelect function, which does the same thing for the next select. I've set up a empty object to store all the options. setOutputObj(outputObj[newParentNode.id] = choice); ands a key value pair to that object. The problem is, if you then try and change the selected option it errors out "TypeError: Cannot create property 'make' on string 'Huawei'".

Here is an example of the date structure I am using.

```
"Fairphone": {
        "3+": {
            "color": ["Black"],
            "storage": ["64GB"], 
        }
    },
    "Doro": {
        "8050": {
            "color": ["Black"],
            "storage": ["16GB"], 
        }
    },
    "Mobiwire": {
        "Smart N12": {
            "color": ["Dark Metallic Blue"],
            "storage": ["16GB"], 
        }
    },
```

Comment: Can you modify the data structure or is it something that you have to stick to?

Comment: At the moment I'm able to structure the data however I please. I have a list of 6 product types. The one above is handsets, which is broken down to manufacturer, then model, storage capacity options, and colors. Would restructuring the structure help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused about your data structure and what you are trying to achieve, but in general, to dynamically set options of a select input from an object I think it's better to use array.map rather than to try to modify the DOM directly.

For example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-buck-8sir5?file=/src/App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const productsByManufacturers = {
  "Manufacturer 1": ["product 1", "product 2", "product 3"],
  "Manufacturer 2": ["product 4", "product 5"]
};

export default function App() {
  const [manufacturer, setManufacturer] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <label>Select Manufacturer:</label>
      <select
        value={manufacturer}
        onChange={(e) => setManufacturer(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="" disabled>
          Select a manufacturer
        </option>
        {Object.keys(productsByManufacturers).map((manufacturer) => (
          <option value={manufacturer}>{manufacturer}</option>
        ))}
      </select>

      {manufacturer !== "" && (
        <div
          style={{ marginTop: 20, display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}
        >
          <label>Select Product:</label>
          <select>
            {productsByManufacturers[manufacturer].map((product) => (
              <option value={product}>{product}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The reason I have structured it as I have is because I want the first dropdown to give the first branch option, which then opens up the other options only based on what is available in that branch. I am trying to avoid the user being able to chose an option for say storage that's not available in the range they have chosen. If I did it the way you have above it only works for two levels of possibilities if I'm understanding you. A manufacturer and a product. I really need the two further options of the color and storage options

Comment: it only works for two levels because I only had two levels in my dummy data.  You could add more layers on the same way if you wanted to.  I think it would be better to restructure your data though.  You should have an array of product objects. Each product object should have a key for each attribute.  E.g [{name: XXX, manufacturer: XXX, color: [XXX, XXX], storage: [XXX, XXX]}, ...more products].  I think it would make it easier to filter through your products using array.filter

Comment: Do you mean something like this: 

`[
{
manufacturer : "Fairphone",
model : "3+",
colors: ["black", "green", "red"],
storage : ["128GB" , "256GB"]
},
{
manufacturer : "Apple",
model : "iphone 12 pro max"",
colors: ["black", "green", "red"],
storage : ["128GB" , "256GB"]
},    
]`

I don't know how that is going to help. You see, I want the first dropdown to always be filled it all manufacturer options and then if they pick Apple, all the apple models are shown in the next drop down. Then when they chose the model the next drop down shows the storage options of that model only.